# jQuery pagination and counting certain divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I have some issues with some JS code we were using to check which products a user has selected to measure against each other.

We were counting the class 'measure-active' with the function .length and all works fine, however recently we have introduced pagination and filters in the form of jQuery, as this breaks the function being able to measure products against each other as you click on another page or filter the products are reloaded and a previous product you have clicked to measure is now not 'active' any longer.

This is the code we have:

```
var linkstart = '/';
var link1 = '';
var link2 = '';
var first;
var second;
var check;
$('input[class="measure-button"]').on('change', function (e) {
    var active = $('input.measure-active').length;
    if($(this).hasClass('measure-active')) { 
        $('input[class="measure-button"]').attr('disabled', false);
        $(this).removeClass('measure-active');
        $('#measure-button').addClass('measure-button-disabled');
        $('#measure-button').attr('href', '#');
        $('#measure-button-two').addClass('measure-button-disabled');
        $('#measure-button-two').attr('href', '#');
        $('.measure-activate').removeClass('shown');
        $('.measure-block').removeClass('measure-inactive');
        //check if this is the first product highlighted, if so do below
        if($(this).data('name') === first) {
            link1 = link2;
            check = 1;
        } else {
            check = 0;
        }
    }
    else if(active == 1) {
        $('input[class="measure-button"]').attr('disabled', true);
        $(this).attr('disabled', false);
        $(this).toggleClass('measure-active');
        $('#measure-button').removeClass('measure-button-disabled');
        $('#measure-button-two').removeClass('measure-button-disabled');
        $('.measure-activate').addClass('shown');
        link2 = $(this).data('company')+'/'+$(this).data('name');
        $('#measure-button').attr('href', linkstart+link1+'/versus/'+link2);
        $('#measure-button-two').attr('href', linkstart+link1+'/versus/'+link2);
        //first = second
        if(check == 1) {
            first = second;
        }
        second = $(this).data('name');
        //dim all other products
        $('.measure-block').addClass('measure-inactive');
    } else if(active != 2) {
        $(this).toggleClass('measure-active');
        $('#measure-button').addClass('measure-button-disabled');
        $('#measure-button-two').addClass('measure-button-disabled');
        $('.measure-activate').removeClass('shown');
        link1 = $(this).data('company')+'/'+$(this).data('name');
        $('#measure-button').attr('href', '#');
        $('#measure-button-two').attr('href', '#');
        first = $(this).data('name');
        $('.measure-block').removeClass('measure-inactive');
    }
    else {
        $(this).removeClass('measure-active');
    }
});
```

Any ideas on how to circumvent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by changing:

```
$('input[class="measure-button"]').on('change', function (e) {
```

to

```
$('body').on('change', 'input[class="measure-button"]', function (e) {
```

And instead of counting with .length, simply adding a variable that counts every time the measure-button is clicked.